Why don't local variable initialisation instructions contribute to the executable size as much as global variables do?
The text I am reading says:

Global variables are located in executable image, so using number of global variables will increase the size of executable image.

Questions:

What does 'located in executable image' mean? From what I have read the global variables are located in the 'data' section of the executable. I presume that local variable initialisation instructions are stored in the 'text' section. So why don't the local variable initialisation instructions take up about the same amount of space as the global variables do?

By executable, does it mean here the executable loaded into the memory or the executable that is only on the non-volatile memory? Will the global variables also take up more space for executable that is not loaded into the RAM?

Are there books or concise reading resources I may refer to that will help me with such lower level concepts?


I expected the size of the local variable initialization instructions to take up the same amount of space in executable as global variables do. Consider the following program:
#include <stdlib.h>

int global_var = 10

int main(void){

    int local_var = 20;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

When converted to machine level executable (assuming its not loaded into memory/not a process), I assume both definition and initialisation of global_var and local_var will be encoded as machine level code, albeit in different sections (data and text) of executable. So why will global_var take up more space?

Have a look at the assembly for the executable at https://godbolt.org/z/s6611E17c - the global variable is there in the executable but the local variable is put into the stack.

SO is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. If you have more than one question, you need to put them in separate posts. In addition, questions asking us to recommend or find books, tutorials, or other off-site resources are specifically indicated as being off-topic in the [help/on-topic] guidelines. You may want to review those guidelines before your next post.

I would suggest it is more that local variable initialization contributes to executable size in a different way. The initial values of globals may be represented as a block of data in the executable file which can be loaded/copied as a block to the storage for the initialized globals by the start up code. Locals may be initialized by executable code that include "immediate" values and is dispersed in appropriate places throughout the code section(s) of the executable.

@AviBerger when you say executable do you mean executable that is in permanent storage or one that is loaded into RAM? Also could you clarify the latter part ‘Locals may be …..of the executable’?

I was actually leaving it mostly ambiguous and not getting into fine details. By executable file, I was thinking of a file produced by a linker and stored quiescent on a mass storage device. Executable Image isn't the same thing, though related and might vary somewhat in different setups. Executable size could be file size, image size, or load size. You can spiral into all sorts of fine details here, and I'm mot sure as important as the general concepts.

For int local_var = 20; in main(), main might have code at entrance that reserves space in a stack frame for local variables. This would provide run time memory storage for local_var. Then main could include an instruction move the immediate value 20 to the memory at that memory address (that was reserved on the stack for local_var). SO the value of 20 here is a part of the code and at run-time is also copied to memory into a space set up at runtime for the variable.

@AviBerger in the dormant binary/executable/machine code, the space that binary representation of 10 and 20 takes ought to be the same, since they are both type 'int'? So won't space taken by instructions, 1. definition/initialisation of global variable 2. instructions to put local_var=20 into stack frame, be the same? Is there a way to represent 20 in binary in such a way that will make it take less space in the dormant executable file.

Yes, a value of 10 or 20 would take the same space. The rest of the instruction also takes space. Fifty such variables set to different values might represent 50 such instructions. Fifty global int variables might mean a data block of 50 values (same space for the values) and a single block copy loop in code to move the values into place. Fifty instructions dispersed throughout the code versus a single loop in the startup code. Or the loader might load the values directly into place without needing the loop. There are many different platforms and details will vary.

How these impact function differs though. And functionality is a major issue. Memory usage or image size aren't the only considerations. What considerations are important varies with platform and situation. And image size and run-time memory usage aren't the same either.

Why don't local variable initialisation instructions contribute to the executable size as much as global variables do?

Global variables are located in executable image, so using number of global variables will increase the size of executable image.

The executable image is the file in which your program resides. For standard C code destined to execute on a Linux environment this would usally be an ELF file. The statement you have provided is correct but does not mention the effect of local variables on the final image.

From what I have read the global variables are located in the 'data' section of the executable.

Correct, global variables are stored in the data or bss section of the ELF file. The data section stores initialized global variables while the bss stores uninitialized ones.

I presume that local variable initialisation instructions are stored in the 'text' section. So why don't the local variable initialisation instructions take up about the same amount of space as the global variables do?

Local variable initialisation instructions always contribute to the size of the code (text section), but might not always affect the size of the final image. This depends on many factors including executable format, alignment and arrangement.
Following is an example of why this scenario might happen on a 32-bit ELF file in Linux.
Let's look at these two program:
// one.c
int a = 0xDEAD;

int main()
{
    int c = 0xBABABABA;
    int b = 0xCAFECAFE;
    int d = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int e = 0x12345678;
    return 0;
}

// two.c
int a = 0xDEAD;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

Pasting the assembly of them:
# one.c
08049000 <main>:
 8049000:   55                      push   %ebp
 8049001:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8049003:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 8049006:   e8 28 00 00 00          call   8049033 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
 804900b:   05 f5 2f 00 00          add    $0x2ff5,%eax
 8049010:   c7 45 fc ba ba ba ba    movl   $0xbabababa,-0x4(%ebp)
 8049017:   c7 45 f8 fe ca fe ca    movl   $0xcafecafe,-0x8(%ebp)
 804901e:   c7 45 f4 ff ff ff ff    movl   $0xffffffff,-0xc(%ebp)
 8049025:   c7 45 f0 78 56 34 12    movl   $0x12345678,-0x10(%ebp)
 804902c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8049031:   c9                      leave  
 8049032:   c3                      ret   

# two.c
08049000 <main>:
 8049000:   55                      push   %ebp
 8049001:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8049003:   e8 0c 00 00 00          call   8049014 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
 8049008:   05 f8 2f 00 00          add    $0x2ff8,%eax
 804900d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8049012:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 8049013:   c3                      ret    

We can clearly see that program one's main function (the entire text section in this case) is larger. And we can even confirm that by looking at the size of the text section in the ELF file:
# one.c
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        08049000 001000 000037 00  AX  0   0  1


# two.c
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        08049000 001000 000018 00  AX  0   0  1

Let's validate by checking the size of each of the two programs (final image) using wc -c. Program one resulted in a 13092 bytes image while program two with exactly the same - 13092 bytes. What's going on?
The reasoning for this conflicting result is related to the alignment of the segments.
Each section is associated with a segment in a table in the ELF file called Section to Segment mapping. Segments contain data that is being loaded as is into memory and is being used at run-time, while sections contain data for linking and relocation. There may be multiple sections in a single segment and not necessarily of the same type.
In program one, our Section to Segment mapping table together with the Program Headers (headers describing segments) is shown below:
# one.c
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x00118 0x00118 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x08049000 0x08049000 0x00037 0x00037 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0804a000 0x0804a000 0x0004c 0x0004c R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x003000 0x0804c000 0x0804c000 0x00010 0x00010 RW  0x1000
  NOTE           0x0000f4 0x080480f4 0x080480f4 0x00024 0x00024 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.build-id 
   01     .text 
   02     .eh_frame 
   03     .got.plt .data 
   04     .note.gnu.build-id 
   05     

Regarding the Program Headers: Offset is the offset of the segment in the file; VirtAddr and PhysAddr indicate the addresses to which this segment should be loaded into; FileSiz is the size of the segment inside the file.
Notice a few thing: the text section is mapped to segment 01, and the data section to segment 03; the FileSiz of segment 01 is 0x37, corresponding to the value we saw before; the Offset of the segments in the file is 0x1000 aligned; segment 01 (of the text section) is before segment 03 (of the data section), which is the last segment in the file.
This alignment of the segments is the reason why although we increased the size of the text section the file itself didn't grow. The 0x1000 bytes in the file between segment 01 and the segment that comes after it will remain 0x1000 as long as our text section contains less than 0x1000 bytes - it will just be padded with zeros as long as not in use. If you happen to have a text section with 0xfff bytes in it and you add 4 more, then your final image will grow by another 0x1000 bytes as the size of the segment containing the text section will now be 0x2000.
And because the data section is being stored in the last segment of the file, there is no need to pad it, meaning that an increase in the size of it will correspond to an increase in the size of the final image.
[Simplified]
This alignment could help the operating system to load the process faster while restricting read/write/execute privileges according to the different sections (a data section will get read/write while a text section read/execute).
An operating system can only allocate blocks of memory with the size of 0x1000; these blocks are called pages. Each page can be set as needed to read/write/execute. If we want our segment containing data to be read/write and our segment containing text to be read/execute we can't place them in the same page.

Are there books or concise reading resources I may refer to that will help me with such lower level concepts?

I think the best way to learn these concepts, or any concept, is by doing. Pick a low level project you would like to write (e.g. hardware driver, compiler, operating system) and do so. This will make sure you understand these concepts and not only think you understand these concepts. Learning C, Assembly, how compilers work and ELF file format is a great start.
so...
Why don't local variable initialisation instructions contribute to the executable size as much as global variables do?
They might contribute and might not. Either way, they will contribute to the size of the text section.

All objects take up memory. If it is initialized, it must be stored somewhere.
However, not all object declarations are equal. Your example there has a global_var that must have a realized int object space somewhere modifiable in your program. That takes space.
But the local local_var is very likely optimized out of existence by your compiler, since the compiler can prove to itself that it is never used (or only used in a context not requiring an actual stored int object anywhere in memory).
The only things necessary are the initial values, which must exist somewhere in the program. Again, since local_var gets elided, so does the requirement to store its initial value.
More explain
This apparently needs a better explanation, since the topic is complex and simplistic reasoning does not apply. The way compilers optimize code and the way linkers link it all together is an expansive topic. I will endeavor to keep this small.
There are several ways to store data in:

your program’s executable (when it is on disk)
your program’s operating memory (when it is executed)

❶ Read-only storage
This kind of storage is used to initialize everything that is not read-only. For example:
int main()
{
  const char * constant_string  = "Hello world!";
  char         mutable_string[] = "Hello world!";
}

Here we have two objects. The character array Hello world!\0 is stored in your executable in the “load into read-only memory” section of the executable file. Only one copy of the array exists in the executable file.
When main() is executed, two variables are created*. The first just directly references the read only memory via a pointer. The second creates a local array on the stack** and copies the data from the read-only memory to your local stack memory.
* Maybe. Keep reading.
** Probably.
You can, of course, modify the local array as much as you like, but if you endeavor to modify the read-only data you’ll get a familiar crash & burn (because the system does not let your program write to memory marked read-only).
⟶ At this point we have considered on-disk and in-memory constant data to be two separate things, but it need not be. On Windows, for example, an executable file is locked and memory-mapped, which makes read-only memory initialization very, very simple for the OS. That is a topic for another conversation, though.
Further, and important to note, this section is used to initialize all initial values in your program, not just global variables. In the example above, both constant_string and mutable_string[] are local variables, but they are initialized using the read-only data.
❷ Global, mutable storage
We call these “global variables”. As mandated by the standard, globals are initialized to zero, unless they have an explicit initial value. Once again, the initial values must exist somewhere. That’s our global read-only storage. Sometime before main() is invoked your global variables are initialized with the values stored in the read-only data section.
I know of no compiler that allows you to elide global variables for any reason. (At least, I’ve never had any need to do that, and haven’t cared to see if it can be done.) You can mark a global variable as static, making it visible only to the individual translation unit (and, therefore, not eligible for inclusion in the object file’s symbol table for use by the linker), but it will still exist as an object taking space in your final executable, and again as another object taking space in memory when your program is executed.
Most times, however, people don’t bother to do even that, and the compiler cannot reasonably do anything but err on the side of caution and make the global variable available in the object file’s symbol table — just so that other translation units have access to it:
// some source file that needs access to `quux.c`’s `quuxlcoatl` variable

extern int quuxlcoatl;

// quux.c

int quuxlcoatl = 5;

So where does that 5 come from?
Correct. It is merged into your executable’s read-only data section, and used to initialize the global variable before main() is invoked.⁂
⁂ Simplified explanation. Wrinkles may apply.
❸ Stack-local storage
Honestly, we’re skipping a number of different kinds of “local storage”, but again, see note ⁂.
Local stack storage is where variables in functions get allocated.
int quuxify( int value )
{
    int quesoso = value * quuxlcoatl;

Here we have two objects on the stack (*,⁑):

value pushed on the stack before quuxify() is invoked
quesoso pushed on the stack after quuxify() is invoked

Both appear to have actual storage space (on the stack). Both are initialized to some value.
Remember that the value of quuxlcoatl may have been changed by some other part of your program, but its initial value also exists in read-only memory.
* Maybe. Keep reading.
⁑ For the moment we will ignore concepts like passing-by-register and other calling conventions.
Stack space is the local-dynamic memory of your program!
It allows your program’s local variables, both mutable and constant, to be created and destroyed as-needed.
The stack itself is pre-allocated space created before main() is invoked, and can be considered a global data store working behind the scenes for you.
⟶ The size of the stack created for your program (by the OS) can be modified, both by flags in the executable file and by requests directly to the OS, but it is always a single, large-ish block of memory that exists when your program is running.
I also think it is possible to have more than one stack in your program, but that is weird stuff, and you can’t quote me on it.
⟶ And since your program has full access rights to its stack memory, it is entirely possible to examine it from anywhere else in your program! This is how, for example, Object Pascal implements access to variables in a containing procedure from a nested procedure, by direct access to the caller’s stack space.
❹ Dynamic memory store
Accessible via the malloc() & free() family of functions. I will skip saying anything about this, as I think it is obvious and does not usefully contribute further to the subject here.
tl;dr: Additional memory your program requests from the OS, obtained in blocks. Does not contribute to the executable file size.
❺ Local object optimizations!
Now we get to the weird and scary stuff.
Just because you wrote and even used a variable in your code, it does not necessarily exist in the final executable code!
Let us revisit our last cheesy example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "quux.h"

int quuxify( int value )
{
    int quesoso = value * quuxlcoatl;
    int parangaricutirimicuaro = 7;
    return quesoso + parangaricutirimicuaro;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf( "%d\n", quuxify( 42 ) );
    return 0;
}

If you were the compiler, you would notice several things you can do to make the code better. One of the primary ways of doing that is: don’t waste time storing and retrieving stuff if you don’t have to!
Register argument storage
First, value doesn’t need to actually exist on the stack! Nothing in the code requires it to. (There is no need to get a pointer to value in the function.)
Consequently, the function can use a very standard, very normal calling convention that expects the first few argument values to be in CPU registers.
⟶ A shocking number of different conventions for invoking functions exist. Specifics vary by platform, but the most common modern x86-specific version is cdecl, which by default passes as many arguments in CPU registers as possible before using the stack.
Thus the caller can just stick the value 42 in the correct register and call the function. No stack space required!
⟶ Keep in mind that the stack space exists whether it is used or not. This is just an optimization that keeps the stack from being used up as fast as it otherwise would be.
Register local storage
We can observe a similar characteristic of the local quesoso object: at no point is there any actual need to create it on the stack. In fact, since value is not used after initializing quesoso, there is no point in hanging on to value. Just multiply it with the global value and thereafter call it quesoso!
Now we have elided quesoso to not exist in any local or global storage space. It exists only in a CPU register!
Literal value elision
Looking now at parangaricutirimicuaro (para-what, now?), we see that it can also be eliminated from actual storage space on the stack.
But now for a different kind of hammer stroke: That 7 that we initialize it with can also disappear. We do not need to store it in the executable’s read-only storage segment.
How?
It is a small constant integer, and can be directly encoded into the compiled machine instructions.
Our function now becomes simple enough that a bunch of stuff that looks like it ought to exist somewhere really only exists in a few words of code.
Function Inlining
Which leads us to our final (potential) optimization: the function itself is just a few small instructions that do not even use any stack space.† Why create the function? Just stick the function’s object code where it is called.
† Lack of use of stack space is not required to consider a function for inlining.
The linker, then, can notice that the function exists, but is not actually invoked (called) by anything (either in this translation unit or any other), and consequently eliminate it from the final executable. (Maybe.)
So, finally, we can answer the title question:

Why don't local variable initialisation instructions contribute to the executable size as much as global variables do?

The answer is: It isn’t that simple. They may or may not.
And whether anything is “likely” depends a whole lot on what options you use to compile your program. A “debug” build will do things significantly less-efficiently than a “release” build, for example.
Generalizations simply do not apply here.
